# from a column, take each 3 values and put them in a row

Tags: bash, shell

I am a beginner, so I appreciate your help. I want to do this with a shell script.
I have a file that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I want to convert it to be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

It's bigger than that, so I need something generic that works for a long file.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for very good first question, including sample data, and required out. (If only ...!).  Next time, be sure to understand the `{}` formatting tool across the top of the input text box. Highlight anything you want to have show 'as-is' then click the `{}`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
awk 'NR%3!=0{printf "%s ",$1;next}1' inputFile
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternate awk solution

```
awk '{ORS = NR % 3 == 0?"\n":" ";} 1' input.txt
```

Comment: +1 Clever use of built-in variables. The braces and semi-colon can be ignored but I guess they provide more readability.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `paste`, for example:

```
seq 9 | paste - - - -d ' '
```

The 3 dashes are to have 3 columns. You add or remove dashes to have more or fewer columns.

The `-d ' '` is to separate the columns by space, because the default is tab.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility:

```
seq 9 | pr -atT -s' ' -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$ seq 9 | sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g'
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```